# How to catch com0com IO-CTL commands?

Tags: c++, serial-port, virtual-serial-port, com0com

I have two connected virtual COM ports (ex. COM0 and COM1), created by [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) driver. Some old application (App1) writes data to COM0 and I read it from COM1 (in App2) and vice-versa.

How can I catch some IO-CTLs from virtual COM port, created by com0com driver (COM1), like baud rate, parity and others?

Of course, I can change nothing in App1 and can do anything in App2.